# standardized way to include unique vcs (e.g. GIT sha) to maven artifact

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt, bintray

I've published my first artifact to bintray, using an SBT project.
However if I ever run into the scenario where I'd like to see the actual code accompanying the binaries, I would have to do the following:

- download the complete source jar (which is normally included in a successful publish of an artifact)
- extract it
- import into IDE
- See where things go wrong, in the case of a bug
- make changes to same code, but in original instance of the project in an IDE, where git is enabled.

Instead of the above, I would preferably like to know the git commit used to create the artifact, then I could check out that commit in my already configured IDE and/or original source directory. Is this use-case catered for?

Comment: You could use git tags to... tag the releases. Per instance, if you are releasing version 1.0.0 you can create a tag v1.0.0. [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) helps you to automate the process.

Comment: Just used it -- works excellent. In my opinion this could be promoted to answer, which I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use git tags to mark commits with the release number/version. Per instance, if you are releasing version 1.0.0 you can create a tag v1.0.0. [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) helps you to automate the process.